# Will I be able to install Ubuntu on Windows 8 Laptops/Ultrabooks?

Tags: windows, secure-boot

I already know that ARM devices with Windows 8 will not allow to install another OS.

What about ultrabooks and laptops with Windows 8, will the secure boot prevent me from installing Ubuntu?

I thought about buying a Ubuntu laptop but unfortunatelly I still must buy Windows license because of some software applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device has an x86 processor, the latest we've heard is that the vendor is required to allow the user to disable secure boot. I have a feeling that it'll be enabled by default, but you should be able to go into the BIOS and disable it.

Still, I would let someone else be the guinea pig:

1. Wait until Windows 8 ultrabooks and laptops are released.
2. Wait until somebody haphazardly buys one intending to install Linux on it.
3. Pick out a model you like.
4. Continuously google for "Microsoft locked me out, I can't disable secure boot on the x86 laptop!!!!!!111oneoneone"
5. If you find no indications of the unit being locked down, go ahead and buy it.

Speculating at this point is not going to be very productive.

Comment: Humm, I see, I sure hope that they don't screw Linux users with this secure-boot, even though I use Windows for some purposes, I can't live without Ubuntu! And since ARM devices are so restrictive, I already made my choice: ultrabook. now just wait and see which models are good for Ubuntu by the end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to compromise a bootloader is if you're getting viruses in the first place.  The problem wouldn't be the bootloader at all.  Microsoft is making a feeble attempt to lock out the competition.  Anyone with enough technical knowledge to install Linux will figure out how to disable Secure Boot.